# How is "tobacco use" differnt from smoking?

Tags: word-meaning

Below quote is from an article I just read, and I'm wondering if there is any difference in meaning between smoking or tobacco use.

"Trachea, bronchus, and lung cancers can affect anyone, but they're most likely to affect those who have a history of ***smoking*** or ***tobacco use***."

https://www.healthline.com/health/top-10-deadliest-diseases#cancers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoking means:

> 2. inhale and exhale the smoke of tobacco or a drug.

Smoking indicates you are enjoying the smoke of the tobacco.

But there is the chewing tobacco, which was once used a lot by baseball players. For the chewing tobacco, you absorb nicotine by chewing and keeping it in the mouth.
You don't smoke the chewing tobacco.

Comment: There was once also "snuff", a powdered form of tobacco for sniffing up the nose.